# Docusign c# sdk error calling getDocument and ListDocuments

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to get all documents already signed from my Docusign account with C# sdk.
So far I can log in but when I try to retrive the documents list or one document it allways give me `DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling ListDocuments: '` or `DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling GetDocument: '` both with 404 status.

Here is the code

```
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string envelopeId = "my_envelop_id";
        string accountId = Init();

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

        //Here is where the exception is thrown
        EnvelopeDocumentsResult docsList = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(accountId, envelopeId);

        // GetDocument() API call returns a MemoryStream
        //var docStream = envApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "my_document_id");
    }

    public string Init()
    {
        // initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(_baseUri);
        Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

        Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", _authHeader);

        // we will retrieve this from the login API call
        string accountId = null;

        // login call is available in the authentication api 
        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

        // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
        accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
        urlCAC = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;

        // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
        apiClient = new ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl);

        return accountId;
    }
```

Any help will be apreciate I am very stuck! Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Finally I got it working. The problem was at the line `apiClient = new ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl);`. When I removed this line all went ok. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: is `accountId` coming correctly from Init() method? also the user used in `_authHeader` is the owner of the envelopeId which you are using to pull document from?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the line with `var envApi = new EnvelopesApi(urlCAC);`

Plugging the baseURL in to the EnvelopesAPI object like this is incorrect. You can see this in Fiddler - Visual Studio will attempt to make a call to `GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents HTTP/1.1` - including the `/v2/accounts/{{accountID/}}` twice

Comment: Thanks for your response, I removed the urlCAC parameter but with same result :(

Comment: It looks like you declare the new API object envApi in line 5, and then the next line 6 you call envelopesApi as the API object. Does it work if you align those to match?

Comment: No, It doesn't work, It was an example of both cases I try with envelope, I will update the question to make it more clear, thanks again